# How to find the exact count of sheets in all excel files

Tags: r, excel, dplyr, filtering

I want to find the count of the number of sheets in all excel files. This is what I did.

```
file_list <- list.files(pattern = '.xlsx',recursive = T)
head(file_list)

[1] "one.xlsx"        [2] "two.xlsx"        
[3] "three.xlsx"    [4] "four.xlsx"
[5] "five.xlsx"
```

So this file_list variable contains around 63 excel files.

```
for (num in file_list) {
   length( excel_sheets( num ) )
}
```

Which results in **NULL** result.

But when I do manually, I am getting the count. For example,

```
length( excel_sheets("../my_excel_directory/one.xlsx") )

[1] 2
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sapply` :

```
file_list <- list.files(pattern = '.xlsx',recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

length(unlist(sapply(file_list, readxl::excel_sheets)))
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak. I got a count of 65.  Is there any way to bind all those excel files together?

Comment: @RuiBarradas-ReinstateMonic `readxl::excel_sheets` returns a vector of sheet names in the excel, using with `sapply` returns a list of sheet names, we then use `length` to calculate all the sheet names. Although, I think I should use `unlist` here.

Comment: @Ronak - When I ran the updated code, I'm getting this error.


Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) :                                                                 
  Column `First Commit Date` can't be converted from POSIXct, POSIXt to numeric
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)